# Rails 3: How to filter "ActiveRecord::Relation" items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filter, scope, ruby-on-rails-3

`products` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I filter some products like this:

```
filtered_products = my_filter(products)
```

where

```
def my_filter(products)
  last_brand_id = last_model_id = nil
  filtered_products = []

  products.each do |product|
    filtered_products << product if (product.model.brand_id != last_brand_id) || (product.model_id != last_model_id)

    last_brand_id = product.model.brand_id
    last_model_id = product.model_id
  end

  filtered_products
end
```

Now I want to order the filtered products:

```
filtered_products.order(...)
```

but I can't do this because `filtered_products` is not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

How should I rewrite `my_filter` so it would return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Or, there is a better solution ?

Comment: It all depends on what the if is - by this i mean is the condition accessible ONLY from the database and not from the ruby code?

Comment: I updated the question. Now you can see the "if" condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you transform your 'my_filter' method into a class method or a scope, so that you'll keep your objects.

EDIT 1:

Let's try to give you a wider solution:

First, declare your filter function:

```
def my_filter(product)
  @last_brand_id ||= nil
  @last_model_id ||= nil
  test = (product.model.brand_id != last_brand_id || product.model_id != last_model_id)
  @last_brand_id = product.model.brand_id
  @last_model_id = product.model_id
  test
end
```

Then fetch the products you want:

```
filtered_products = products.select{|p| p if my_filter(p)}
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to do this ? (I updated the question)

Comment: I'm confused: is the end statement of the 'products.each do |product|' at the right place? don't you update last_brand_id and last_model_id before looping again?

Comment: ok, I won't do your job but go to http://www.scribd.com/doc/33191538/48/Using-Procs-for-Filtering-matching-members-rb  and read from page 128

Comment: I don't see how it is related to `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You suggest to put `my_filter` in what class ?

Comment: I've just proposed you some implementation